# How do I match a regex based on the priority of the expression?

Tags: regex

If I have the following data:

```
abc1dogs
a1cat2dogs
turtles
```

and I want to extract all text either following a "1" a "2" or if the line does not contain a "1" or a "2"?  The additional rule that needs to be used is that if a "1" and a "2" exist in the record then I want only the value after the "2" to be extracted.  I tried using:

```
(?<=[12])(.*)
```

That came close but it returned:

```
dogs
cat2dogs
```

What I want it to return is:

```
dogs
dogs
turtles
```

Answer (score 2):

This slightly bloated one works with a PCRE regex engine:

```
(?<=2).*|(?<=1)[^2]*$|^[^12]*$
```

It makes sure that (if it found a `1`) the rest of the string does not contain `2`s. Likewise, if the whole string is to be matched, there are no `1`s and `2`s allowed in the string.

Comment: I'm using http://regex.powertoy.org/ (Java Regex syntax).  That only returns "dogs" from the second line

Comment: Do you use that just for testing or will you use that ultimately? The problem is, that it does not support multi-line mode (otherwise, `$` would match line-endings as well). If you just add your input as single lines, it will work (and if you use tool supporting multi-line mode, you will get exactly the same result)

Answer (score 0):

Simple

`[^12\n]*$`

Tested like this:

[image]